# Copy only a sample to another queue in rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I would like to have an exchange that automatically copy only a certain amount of messages (let's say 10%) to another queue (possibly via shovel)

Is this possible?

Comment: `exchanges` don't contain messages, and 10% respect of?

Comment: In fact, I would like to have 10% of an incoming queue or exchange copied to another queue/exchange. I want to do some sampling